# How to get the taskmanager's app list without any background services?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, windows-11

I'm trying get the current used apps in the list. In order to get the list, I have used the below code to retrieve the applications from the windows machine. When I run the below code, It gives few application names but also, gives values like Media Player, ApplicationFrameHost, Settings etc. When I checked with the task manager, these apps are present in the [background apps tab](https://prnt.sc/K8K7SUlzKhqv). I'm not able to split it and get the values.

```
    public enum WindowState
    {
        Normal,
        Minimized,
        Maximized
    }

    public class WindowWrapper : IWin32Window
    {
        private IntPtr _handle;
        private string _title;
        private WindowState _state;

        public IntPtr Handle => _handle;
        public string Title => _title;
        public WindowState State => _state;

        public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle, string title, WindowState state)
        {
            _handle = handle;
            _title = title;
            _state = state;
        }
    }

    public class NativeMethods
    {
        public static readonly IntPtr GWL_STYLE = new IntPtr(-16);
        public static readonly UInt64 WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000L;
        public static readonly UInt64 WS_BORDER = 0x00800000L;
        public static readonly UInt64 DESIRED_WS = WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE;

        public delegate bool EnumWindowsCallback(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
        {
            public int length;
            public int flags;
            public int showCmd;
            public POINT ptMinPosition;
            public POINT ptMaxPosition;
            public RECT rcNormalPosition;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        public static List<WindowWrapper> GetAllWindows()
        {
            List<WindowWrapper> windows = new List<WindowWrapper>();

            EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr.Zero, (hwnd, lParam) =>
            {
                if ((GetWindowLongA(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & DESIRED_WS) == DESIRED_WS && !IsIconic(hwnd)
                    && IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && IsWindow(hwnd) && hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(255);
                    GetWindowText(hwnd, buffer, buffer.Capacity);
                    string title = buffer.ToString();

                    WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
                    placement.length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));
                    GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, ref placement);

                    WindowState state = WindowState.Normal;

                    int processId;
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out processId);

                    var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);

                    if (IsProcessInForeground(processId))
                    {
                        state = WindowState.Normal;  // Consider it as normal if it's in the foreground
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch (placement.showCmd)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                state = WindowState.Normal;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                state = WindowState.Minimized;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                state = WindowState.Maximized;
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    WindowWrapper wnd = new WindowWrapper(hwnd, title, state);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(wnd.Title) /*&& !string.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle) */&& !process.HasExited && process.MainWindowHandle == hwnd)
                    {
                        windows.Add(wnd);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }, IntPtr.Zero);

            return windows;
        }

        private static bool IsProcessInForeground(int processId)
        {
            IntPtr foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
            int foregroundProcessId;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindow, out foregroundProcessId);

            return (foregroundProcessId == processId);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumWindowsCallback lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

        private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern void GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern UInt64 GetWindowLongA(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr nIndex);
    }
```

The question here is How do I segregate the app list from the background apps as like Task manager? Attached image [here](https://prnt.sc/2AFWy7RhGNV6).

Comment: You don't need interop for this, you can use `Process.GetProcesses()` to get all processes and check which ones have no `MainWindowHandle`. There's no `background app` process type. Task Manager considers any process that has no window to be a "background app". If you want to list and control services you can use [ServiceController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

Comment: What are you trying to do though? You used the `asp.net` tag which suggests you're building a web applications. Web servers rarely have any interactive users which means all processes will be "background apps", unless someone RDPs to the server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, We have two items in the task manager. One is apps and other one is background apps. Check the attached image in the above one. I have used the code which you have mentioned as well. Please check below and let me know your thoughts on it.

Code image: https://prnt.sc/8ov6Cz8oav9f
Output image: https://prnt.sc/01KSmLSWbmWy

I have marked few items which are in the background apps in task manager.

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate checks `MainWindowHandle` not `MainWindowTitle`.

Comment: I have checked that as well and we are not able to do that @PanagiotisKanavos. Attached image for your reference.

Image: https://prnt.sc/9NHCwMtN4qwQ